# passing audio from mongodb to audio tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, html5-audio, gridfs

For my project I'm trying to create an audio player. The database aspect of storing files is new to me as I've only stored strings before.

So far, what I've been able to do is:

1. Store the audio file into the database.(I'm linking to a file here for simplicity but in the future it will be uploaded)
2. Retrieve the audio file as an object.
3. Store the audio file in the public folder for use.

**Server side code**(the route code is separate from the server code)

```js
let fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
})

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const Binary = require('mongodb').Binary;
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/music', function(req, res) {

      //STEP ONE

      var data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../public/recordings/Piso 21 - Puntos Suspensivos.mp3');
      var insert_data = {};
      insert_data.name = 'Piso 21 - Puntos Suspensivos.mp3';
      insert_data.file_data = Binary(data);

      MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/songs", {
        useNewUrlParser: true
      }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("songs");
        dbo.collection("song").insertOne(insert_data, function(err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document inserted");
          db.close();
        });
      });

      //STEP TWO

      MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/songs", {
        useNewUrlParser: true
      }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("songs");
        dbo.collection("song").findOne({
          name: 'Piso 21 - Puntos Suspensivos.mp3'
        }, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          db.close();

          //STEP THREE

          fs.writeFile(result.name, result.file_data.buffer, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
          });
        });
      });
      res.render('audio');
    });
```

The third step is what I don't what to do. I'd like to send the `result` object to the `audio.ejs` page and somehow give the `audio tag` access to it without having to save it in the public folder an then have to delete it after use.

Something like this,

**STEP THREE**

```
  res.render('audio', result);
```

and somehow give an `audio tag` access to it in the `audio.ejs` page

**UPDATE**

```
let fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
const Binary = require('mongodb').Binary;
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

const db = new MongoClient.Db('songs', new MongoClient.Server("localhost", 27017));
const gfs = Grid(db, MongoClient);

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(app){


    app.get('/audio/:filename', function (req, res) {

        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/songs", { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("songs");
            dbo.collection("song").findOne({name: req.params.filename}, function(err, result){
                if (err) throw err;
                db.close();
                const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(result.file_data);
                readstream.on('error', function (error) {
                    res.sendStatus(500);
                });
                console.log(res);
                res.type('audio/mpeg');
                readstream.pipe(res);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old-timey database lingo media objects are called BLOBS -- binary large objects. In Mongo they're handled with a [subsystem known as `gridfs`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). There's a nice [npm module called gridfs-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gridfs-stream) to make this easier.

An easy way to deliver media objects to browsers is to make them available behind URLs that look like `https://example.com/audio/objectname.mp3`. And, they should be delivered with the a[ppropriate `Content-Type` header for the codec in use](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#audio) (`audio/mpeg` for MP3). Then the src tag can simply name the URL and you're rockin' and rollin'. The audio tag in the browser page looks something like this:

```
<audio controls src="/audio/objectname.mp3" ></audio>
```

So, if you want to deliver audio directly via express, you need a route with a parameter, something like

```
 app.get('/audio/:filename', ...
```

Then the node program uses something like this **not debugged!**)

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
...
const db = new mongo.Db('yourDatabaseName', new mongo.Server("host", 27017));
const gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
...
app.get('/audio/:filename', function (req, res) {
   const readstream = gfs.createReadStream({filename: req.params.filename})
   readstream.on('error', function (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500)
   })
   res.type('audio/mpeg')
   readstream.pipe(res)
});
```

This is cool because streams are cool: your node program doesn't need to slurp the whole audio file into RAM. Audio files can be large.

gridfs offers the [`mongofiles` command line utilit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles)y for loading files into gridfs.

But, all that being said:  Most scalable media services use static media files delivered from file systems and/or content delivery networks. Servers like apache and nginx have many programmer years invested in making file delivery fast and efficient.  The database holds the pathnames for the files in the CDN.

How to troubleshoot this kind of thing?

- Watch the browser's console log.
- Hit the media URL directly from a browser. See what you get. If it's empty, something's wrong with your retrieval code.
- In dev tools in the browser, look at the Network tab (in Google Chrome). Look for the media object, and examine what's going on.

Comment: Really nice answer. I was trying to avoid gridfs for now, but this looks pretty understandable. Thank you. I  have some questions though. I'm guessing I have to make an ajax request on the client side. if so what do I put for the file location `xhttp.open("GET", "file location", true);` and is this how I specify the content type?
`xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "audio/mpeg");`

Comment: The `src` attribute in the audio tag will cause the browser to retrieve your audio file, without need for any complicated ajax. If I were you I'd get that to work first.

Comment: So I've been trying to get this to work but I can't. I have updated it a little to match my existing code. Please take a look. I updated my question. I think the error is in this line `    const db = new MongoClient.Db('songs', new MongoClient.Server("localhost", 27017));` . My database name is `songs`. and the  collection name is `song`. I don't understand how the collection is being searched by just entering the database name.

Comment: Read the stuff about GridFS. Notice that it has its own indexing scheme. The objects you pull out with GridFS must be put in there by the same means. That's why I mentioned `mongofiles`. You can replace the example code I gave you for getting into Mongo with your code that works.

Comment: Your mongofiles link doesn't word. Can you please update it?

Comment: Ok, so taking your advice I rewrote the update please have a look. I managed to not get any errors but the audio doesn't play.

Comment: I always look at the console log in dev tools. There isn't any errors.  The network tab, nothing shows up. clicking the `audio src` link directly gives `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` even though `console.log(result)` shows that the object was found and placed in `result` and that `console.log(result.file_data)` does give the buffer.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but hopefully it helps someone having the same problem as me that is a bit more experience in web development. Thank you for trying to assist me. much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a stream, so you can stream data from the server to the webpage  directly without saving it. Node js comes with this functionality more of it from the documentation here https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html